# Performance implications of Spark Pipelines

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using an `SQLTransformers` we can create new columns in a dataframe and have a `Pipeline` of these `SQLTransformers` as well. We can do the same thing using multiple calls to `selectExpr` methods on dataframes too.

But are the performace optimization metrics that are applied to the selectExpr calls applied to a pipeline of `SQLTransformers` as well?

For example consider the two snippets of code below:

```
#Method 1
df = spark.table("transactions")
df = df.selectExpr("*","sum(amt) over (partition by account) as acc_sum")
df = df.selectExpr("*","sum(amt) over (partition by dt) as dt_sum")
df.show(10)

#Method 2
df = spark.table("transactions")
trans1 = SQLTransformer(statement ="SELECT *,sum(amt) over (partition by account) as acc_sum from __THIS__")
trans2 = SQLTransformer(statement ="SELECT *,sum(amt) over (partition by dt) as dt_sum from __THIS__")
pipe = Pipeline(stage[trans1,trans2])
transPipe = pipe.fit(df)
transPipe.transform(df).show(10)
```

Will the performance for both of these ways of computing the same thing be the same?

Or will there be some extra optimizations that are applied to method 1 that are not used in method 2?

Comment: It's DataFrames under the hood (and RDD under that) so mainly the optimizer works the same way on the execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No additional optimizations. As always, when in doubt, check execution plan:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1, 1)], ("amt", "account", "dt"))

(df
    .selectExpr("*","sum(amt) over (partition by account) as acc_sum")
    .selectExpr("*","sum(amt) over (partition by dt) as dt_sum")
    .explain(True))
```

generates:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [*, 'sum('amt) windowspecdefinition('dt, unspecifiedframe$()) AS dt_sum#165]
+- AnalysisBarrier Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#158L]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
amt: bigint, account: bigint, dt: bigint, acc_sum: bigint, dt_sum: bigint
Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#158L, dt_sum#165L]
+- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#158L, dt_sum#165L, dt_sum#165L]
   +- Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(dt#24L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS dt_sum#165L], [dt#24L]
      +- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#158L]
         +- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#158L]
            +- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#158L, acc_sum#158L]
               +- Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(account#23L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS acc_sum#158L], [account#23L]
                  +- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L]
                     +- LogicalRDD [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(dt#24L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS dt_sum#165L], [dt#24L]
+- Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(account#23L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS acc_sum#158L], [account#23L]
   +- LogicalRDD [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L], false

== Physical Plan ==
Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(dt#24L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS dt_sum#165L], [dt#24L]
+- *Sort [dt#24L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(dt#24L, 200)
      +- Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(account#23L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS acc_sum#158L], [account#23L]
         +- *Sort [account#23L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(account#23L, 200)
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[amt#22L,account#23L,dt#24L]
```

while

```
trans2.transform(trans1.transform(df)).explain(True)
```

generates

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [*, 'sum('amt) windowspecdefinition('dt, unspecifiedframe$()) AS dt_sum#150]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation `SQLTransformer_4318bd7007cefbf17a97_826abb6c003c`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
amt: bigint, account: bigint, dt: bigint, acc_sum: bigint, dt_sum: bigint
Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#120L, dt_sum#150L]
+- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#120L, dt_sum#150L, dt_sum#150L]
   +- Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(dt#24L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS dt_sum#150L], [dt#24L]
      +- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#120L]
         +- SubqueryAlias sqltransformer_4318bd7007cefbf17a97_826abb6c003c
            +- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#120L]
               +- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L, acc_sum#120L, acc_sum#120L]
                  +- Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(account#23L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS acc_sum#120L], [account#23L]
                     +- Project [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L]
                        +- SubqueryAlias sqltransformer_4688bba599a7f5a09c39_f5e9d251099e
                           +- LogicalRDD [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(dt#24L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS dt_sum#150L], [dt#24L]
+- Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(account#23L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS acc_sum#120L], [account#23L]
   +- LogicalRDD [amt#22L, account#23L, dt#24L], false

== Physical Plan ==
Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(dt#24L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS dt_sum#150L], [dt#24L]
+- *Sort [dt#24L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(dt#24L, 200)
      +- Window [sum(amt#22L) windowspecdefinition(account#23L, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS acc_sum#120L], [account#23L]
         +- *Sort [account#23L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(account#23L, 200)
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[amt#22L,account#23L,dt#24L]
```

As you can see optimized and physical plans are identical.

Comment: I'm happy there is someone who writes answers instead of me :) I think I'm getting old

Comment: Thanks! That was a very nice way to explain it too. Didnt think I could use the explain plan for something that goes through a pipeline; sliped me mind!

Comment: @SubramaniamRamasubramanian everything that products a `Dataset`/`DataFrame` has a plan thus an `explain`. You can always refer to the doc in all cases.